# Python3 connecting to MSSQL

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, ide, connection

I am writing Python3 and we have a database(mssql).
I have some strings and want to put these strings into db table. But I could not handle connecting to DB. Some people suggested using pyodbc but my python version is 3.4.4 and pyodbc is not supporting it. I am writing my codes in PyCharm IDE and I am not using anyother IDE such as Visual Studio, Eclipse, etc. DB is created and the table exists.

- Which programs or libraries do I need?
- Which lines that I should write to code (like `import pypmssql`)

Language: Python3 version 3.4.4
IDE: PyCharm latest version
DB: MSSQL

Comment: Did you look here? http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mssql.html

Answer (score 1):

If you work on a Linux distribution, try to install pip3 (python dependency manager for python 3) then run

```
pip install pymssql
```

Then read the library documention to learn how to use it at http://pymssql.org/en/latest/

Comment: Connection is timed out :( It is probably due to my network access privileges. Is there anyother way ? I tried to download it manually from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pymssql/2.1.2#downloads but I do not know how to install the downloaded md5 file

Comment: Try to download the whl file from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pymssql/2.1.2#downloads then run pip3 install pymssql-2.1.2-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl

Comment: pymssql-2.1.2-cp34-cp34m-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Comment: Try to download another file format (you have downloaded the win32 version)

Comment: I tried all of them in https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pymssql/2.1.2#downloads

but not working :( always saying wheel is not supported on this platform

Comment: Have you tried to run pip3 install on the tar.gz file ? What is your operating system ?